# Rules for accessing a domain to root in web.config

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, web-config, rules

Should provide rule in web.config:

Only **domain.com** access to this root. so if **domain1.com** request, I should to avoid accessing.

```
<rules>
<rule name="check access" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="www.domain.com/{R:0}" ignoreCase="false" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
<add 
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="www.domain.com/NotAccess" />
</rule>
</rules>
```